# Interface missed after namespace removal

Tags: networking

After namespace removal Ubuntu doesn't have an network interface, which was attached to the container. There is no any namespaces in my environment:

```
$ ls -la /var/run/netns/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  40 Sep 18 13:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 940 Sep 18 13:21 ..
```

Nevertheless interface can not be created:

```
$ sudo vconfig add eth1 268
ERROR: trying to add VLAN #268 to IF -:eth1:-  error: File exists

$ sudo ip link show eth1.268
Device "eth1.268" does not exist.
```

Any ideas how to find the missed interface? Sure there is my fault that I forgot to assign the interface from namespace to netns 1 (host system), but I don't believe that it has gone...

Strace is not very informative:

```
# strace vconfig add eth1 268
execve("/sbin/vconfig", ["vconfig", "add", "eth1", "268"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1742000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe6bb754000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=53226, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 53226, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe6bb747000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P \2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1840928, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3949248, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe6bb16f000
mprotect(0x7fe6bb329000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fe6bb529000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1ba000) = 0x7fe6bb529000
mmap(0x7fe6bb52f000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe6bb52f000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe6bb746000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe6bb744000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fe6bb744740) = 0
mprotect(0x7fe6bb529000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x601000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fe6bb756000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fe6bb747000, 53226)           = 0
open("/proc/net/vlan/config", O_RDONLY) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFVLAN, 0x7ffc432b83c0)   = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
write(2, "ERROR: trying to add VLAN #268 t"..., 66ERROR: trying to add VLAN #268 to IF -:eth1:-  error: File exists
) = 66
exit_group(3)                           = ?
+++ exited with 3 +++
```

Answer (score 6):

This happens when a process is left running in the namespace after the namespace is removed. You need to stop/kill this process before adding the same interface again.
If you can't find the process, you could search for the interface name with find in /proc, eg.:

```
root@linx:~# vconfig add enp1s0 10
ERROR: trying to add VLAN #10 to IF -:enp1s0:-  error: File exists

root@linx:~# find /proc/ -name enp1s0.10
/proc/18557/task/18557/net/vlan/enp1s0.10
/proc/18557/task/18557/net/dev_snmp6/enp1s0.10
/proc/18557/net/vlan/enp1s0.10
/proc/18557/net/dev_snmp6/enp1s0.10

root@linx:~# kill -9 18557

root@linx:~# vconfig add enp1s0 10
Added VLAN with VID == 10 to IF -:enp1s0:-
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: Good answer. Here is a one liner to remove them all with one command if found:
`for i in $(sudo find /proc/ -name "enp1s0.10"| grep task | awk -F'/' '{print$3}'); do sudo kill -9 $i; done`